# bstreeview - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'nodeId' on string '['

Tags: treeview

Part of my JS file that initialize bstreeview:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.origin + '/build-filter-values/',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data)
        $('#tree').bstreeview({
          data: data
        });
    }
})
```

console.log(data) show an valid array :

```
[{text: "Calcareous nanofossils", id: "1", parent: "None", nodes:[{text: "Aggregates", id: "19", parent: "1", }]},{text: "Crinoids", id: "18", parent: "None", }]
```

I have an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'nodeId' on string '['

On the other hand, what is strange is that when I set the array in a variable in another file and I build my treeview with this variable, it works, whereas it is strictly the same array...

```
//file mytree.js:

var tree = [{text: "Calcareous nanofossils", id: "1", parent: "None", nodes:[{text: "Aggregates", id: "19", parent: "1", }]},{text: "Crinoids", id: "18", parent: "None", }];


// another file js
 $('#tree').bstreeview({
      data: tree
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
The problem was in my back (python)
I tried to build my tree in a String instead of building an objects.
So I was trying to serialize a String instead of an object by doing:

```
 return HttpResponse(json.dumps(tree))
```

tree